# RNN provides weird output as the sample size is increased

Tags: neural-networks, sample-size, accuracy, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently training an RNN with an underlying binary classification problem (0 and 1). I increased the sample size drastically to see whether the performance is increased. The problem is that now, the NN returns for every single entry in my test sample 1. The out of sample accuracy is 70.73% but that's just because the test sample consists of 70.73% as 1 for the correct prediction.

A NN that just tells me for any input that its class 1 seems pretty useless right? However, for a lower sample size the network returned 0's and 1's where the out of sample accuracy was around 50-60%. Is it correct to conclude that the sample size can be too large for a network to work properly? I thought that a too large sample size can only be disadvantageous in case it reduces the accuracy by increasing the noise in the dataset.

Comment: Might be interesting to add, even if I change the construction of the model (layers,nods) or even if I change the features that are used, I still get the 70.73%.

Comment: If you choose the out-of-sample accuracy as a measurement of the quality, the one with a larger sample size is better than the one with lower sample size. If 70% are from one class, 50-60% is a pretty bad outcome, and classifying everything to class 1 is better than that, like it or not. You may improve on that setting up the RNN (actually better explain abbreviations because they can have various meanings) in a different way, but certainly this is not a case in which a smaller sample size looks better, at least not to me.

Comment: You might look into better measures of prediction qualiy, search this site for proper [tag:scoring-rules]